How can I reload a modified class at runtime in Java?
I am writing my bachelor thesis about libraries for runtime code manipulation in Java. I have to work on a profiler for the practical part that can inject code into loaded classes which are marked with an annotation. I am working with the new Java ClassFile API and everything works as planned up to the point where I want my changes to take effect.
I have transformed the method bodies of some methods in a class (to include timers, etc., to measure how long a function takes, etc.) and now I have a byte array containing the modified class. The issue now is that I can't figure out how to load this new class and make its changes affect all following instances of the modified classes.
Test before = new Test();
before.doNothing();

Profiler profiler = Profiler.getInstance();
profiler.inject();

Test after = new Test();
after.doNothing();

This is the test code. The Test class has a function that does nothing literally, the bytecode is just a return. The profiler injects bytecode of a print statement that prints 20. But it's not being affected by any changes. I tried loading it with a custom class loader, and I was able to create a new instance of that custom loaded class and it printed 20, but that did not override the actual Test class, but create an additional one, and the doNothing of the actual Test class was still the same, doing nothing.
So by that, I know that the modification itself works, it's just not properly applied. I need a way to update the class globally somehow with the new class I have in a byte array (I can also write it in a temp file if that helps), and it should just happen at runtime, no actual overwriting or compile-time stuff.

If all you want to do is transform the body of a method, then you can do that via instrumentation. Here is an example which:

Transforms the Greeter#greet() method to print "Goodbye, World!" instead of "Hello, World!".

Uses the Java 22 Class-File API preview feature (see java.lang.classfile) to transform the method body to match what you're doing in your question. Note using that API is not a requirement; you can use any other byte-code manipulation library to perform the transformation. Technically, you could even implement your own code/library for this, though I wouldn't recommend doing so.

Note the Class-File API will still be a preview feature in Java 23 (with some API changes).


Registers the agent with Launcher-Agent-Class, which is specific to executable JARs. See the java.lang.instrument package documentation for alternatives.

Has the agent designed in a way that allows transforming the Greeter class at an arbitrary point in time (rather than immediately when the agentmain method is invoked).


Note the retransformation affects instances of the class created before the retransformation. Also note the implementation of ExampleAgent is only good enough for the example (for instance, it doesn't check if you've already invoked #retransformGreeterClass()).
Source Code
Greeter.java
package com.example;

public class Greeter {

  public void greet() {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}

Main.java
package com.example;

public final class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var greeter = new Greeter();

    greeter.greet();
    ExampleAgent.retransformGreeterClass();
    greeter.greet();
  }
}

ExampleAgent.java
package com.example;

import static java.lang.classfile.ClassTransform.transformingMethodBodies;

import java.lang.classfile.ClassFile;
import java.lang.classfile.CodeBuilder;
import java.lang.classfile.CodeElement;
import java.lang.classfile.Instruction;
import java.lang.classfile.MethodModel;
import java.lang.classfile.Opcode;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class ExampleAgent {

  private static Instrumentation inst;

  public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
    ExampleAgent.inst = inst;
  }

  public static void retransformGreeterClass() {
    inst.addTransformer(new GreeterClassFileTransformer(), true);
    try {
      inst.retransformClasses(Greeter.class);
    } catch (UnmodifiableClassException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }

  private static class GreeterClassFileTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    @Override
    public byte[] transform(
        ClassLoader loader,
        String className,
        Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
        ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
        byte[] classfileBuffer) {
      if ("com/example/Greeter".equals(className)) {
        var cf = ClassFile.of();
        return cf.transform(
            cf.parse(classfileBuffer),
            transformingMethodBodies(this::isGreetMethod, this::acceptGreetMethodElement));
      }
      return null;
    }

    private boolean isGreetMethod(MethodModel model) {
      return model.methodName().equalsString("greet");
    }

    private void acceptGreetMethodElement(CodeBuilder builder, CodeElement element) {
      if (element instanceof Instruction i && i.opcode() == Opcode.LDC) {
        builder.ldc("Goodbye, World!");
      } else {
        builder.with(element);
      }
    }
  }
}

Manifest
MANIFEST.MF
Main-Class: com.example.Main
Launcher-Agent-Class: com.example.ExampleAgent
Can-Retransform-Classes: true

Project Directory
<PROJECT-DIR>
|
\---src
    +---com
    |   \---example
    |           ExampleAgent.java  
    |           Greeter.java       
    |           Main.java
    |
    \---META-INF
            MANIFEST.MF

Building & Executing
Working directory is <PROJECT-DIR>.
Compiling:
javac --enable-preview --release 22 --source-path src -d out/classes src/com/example/*.java

Packaging:
jar cfm out/example.jar src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -C out/classes .

Executing:
java --enable-preview -jar out/example.jar

Output
Hello, World!
Goodbye, World


As said in the comments to the question, this will not modify the existing class. It will instead modify the class when it's used for the first time. The "before" Test instance will already have these changes applied.

Maybe I'm missing something about the question, but my answer clearly shows an existing class was modified at runtime (without needing a different class loader). This is something instrumentation is designed for. And it should work for the OP, at least if all they want to do is modify the body of a method, which is what I understood the OP's goal to be.

And note the code in my main method and the output. The class is loaded, an instance is created, and the greet method is invoked. That prints out "Hello, World!". Then I apply the retransformation, followed by another call to greet. That now prints "Goodbye, World!" (due to the retransformation). In other words, the changes are applied on demand, not when the class is first used.

You're right, I must have missed something when first reading your answer.

Ah.  This is a new Java 22 feature.  Need to read about it ...

@StephenC The java.lang.classfile.* API is definitely new in Java 22. But hasn't instrumentation always (or at least for a long while) been able to modify a class at runtime? I was under the impression that's how profilers work, even those that can dynamically connect (instead of, e.g., -javaagent) to a running JVM.

I didn't know that ...

@StephenC the Instrumentation API had been added in Java 5.
